# How to be informed about a new branch in git?

Tags: git

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but didn't know what to search for.
I am going to use partly informal concepts, because I am not fully aware of the exact functions of each git command.

---

I want a way to see all changes made to the repo, with no effect on any local branch, including the one I am currently on.

---

**A minimal scenario:**

Bob is on branch 'master', which is empty.

Alice clones the repo, and is also on the empty 'master'.

Alice commits to 'master' and pushes to 'origin/master'

Mario creates a new branch 'mario' and pushes it to 'origin/mario'.

Here Bob sees an empty master.

Bob wants to keep his 'master' the same, but be aware that changes were made to 'origin/master', and that a new branch 'mario' has been created.

What command should bob use?

Comment: `git fetch` is the tool to update your remote-tracking branches. It'll show the creation of `mario` and also the new ref `origin/master` is pointing to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing `git fetch`. You are describing it perfectly! It syncs the remote down to `origin/master` and `origin/mario` (and all other remote-tracking branches) with no effect on local branches.

Basically you just fetch and then “look around” to see what’s happened; effectively, you are now inspecting the remote. For example, you might say:

```
git fetch
git branch --all -vv
git log --oneline origin/master
```

It is safe to fetch, so do it often, whenever you’re curious about the state of the remote.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `git fetch origin`, you get a summary of other branches that were created since the last pull or fetch.

This keeps master the same. However, it downloads remote changes locally, so that the next `pull` or `merge` does not need to.

Answer (score 0):

**git fetch** use to collect changes from remote, running that command will let bob know that is branch is behind and new change being pushed to master

**git pull** will download the changes from remote

**git pull --rebase** will download changes from remote and rebase it with its local, so bob local changes will come on top of remote/origin